# Reconize a card from a video stream

Tags: neural-network, classification, image-classification, computer-vision

I want to make an mobile app where you scan using the camera and it gives you the card you just scanned. (from a board game)
I got a PNG of each and every single existing cards, but I don't really know what to use.

For now, I've been using the text in the card using OCR to find the card, but it's not 100% accurate as the typography is pretty special.

I've been thinking about using image classification, but I'm not sure it's the right way to do it, as I would be training for hundreds of classes. (got over 400+ different cards)

Do you have any idea what I should be using ? (I'm sorry if this seems like a basic question, but I just started learning about CV and ANN)
Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 1):

**First Approach:**

You can probably train a CNN ( Convolutional Neural Network ) on the images you have. If the number of images is less, I prefer you to use [Transfer Learning](https://towardsdatascience.com/transfer-learning-for-image-classification-using-keras-c47ccf09c8c8).

> In Transfer learning, we have a highly trained model ( like Inception, ResNet ) and we modify it so that it can classify images which we need.

**Second Approach:**

Use object detection. You need to localize an object ( card ) from the image and then classify that cropped image. This could be tedious if you're a beginner.

You can refer to these links:

- https://tensorflow-object-detection-api-tutorial.readthedocs.io/en/latest/training.html
- https://towardsdatascience.com/creating-your-own-object-detector-ad69dda69c85
- https://pythonprogramming.net/training-custom-objects-tensorflow-object-detection-api-tutorial/

> You need to train a localization model which can track and crop your images ( of cards ).